# 2 users but 0 sessions?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

The screenshot below is showing pages reached via google/organic.

I'm confused by the highlighted row below. How can I have 2 users for this page with 0 sessions (and 0 everything else).

I'm assuming it's not a bot if the source/medium is googleorganic?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: One reason this happens is if sessions do not start with (or do not even include) a pageview, which might point to a programming problem, but until that's confirmed I tend to agree with the close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal as the "sessions" metric is only incremented on the FIRST hit of the session. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2934985?hl=en

Comment: So essentially sessions just means entry pages? That seems weird.

Comment: The difference is sessions is a metric while entry pages is a custom dimension.

Comment: Ok. So a session is a metric meaning 'this page was the entry page to the site' X times. It's that correct?

Comment: Yes, when you pair a page level dimension, ie page, and the sessions metric, it essentially shows which page incremented the sessions count. Sessions count only increments on entry page.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!